# Http request takes too long for main thread but is needed

Tags: java, android-studio

If I try requesting something from HTTP OnClick, it takes too long to complete the request and so I get a MainThread error that it’s taking too long. If I try to place it on a back thread, the contents aren’t where i need them to be by the time I need to use them.

My code is capable of parsing a JSON string, but the problem I have is getting the string from the server takes forever and doesn't get there by the time I need to parse.

It only works for me when I use the debugging tool, place a breakpoint before the request and after. Then, the string is there quick enough to parse.

FYI: I tried client.execute() and that resulted in a main thread issue which is why I now used client.enqueue() but then i don't get the data on time for the parsing.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Error:

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.weather_app, PID: 2774
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:402)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
      **at com.example.weather_app.MainActivity.button1Pressed(MainActivity.java:91)**
```

My Button implementation: (error at: "** .... **")

```
public void button1Pressed(View view) {

        Log.i("event", "Button 1 Pressed");
        final TextView temperature = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.Temperature);
        final TextView humidity = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.Humidity);
        final TextView wind_speed = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.Wind_Speed);
        final TextView precipitation =   (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.Precipitation);

        fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {

                if(location != null) {
                    Log.i("location", location.toString());

                    String url = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/6e5fd8e33301bec5482dd3656d16cb32/" + location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude();
                    getAndParseData(url);
                }
            }
        });

        **temperature.setText(String.valueOf(weatherDataList.get(0).getHourly().getSummary()));**
        humidity.setText(String.valueOf(weatherDataList.get(0).getCurrently().getHumidity()));
        wind_speed.setText(String.valueOf(weatherDataList.get(0).getCurrently().getWindSpeed()));
      precipitation.setText(String.valueOf(weatherDataList.get(0).getCurrently().getPrecipIntensity()));
    }
```

Get and Parse Data from HTTP:

```
    void getAndParseData(String url){

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    data = "[" + response.body().string() + "]";
                    parseData(data);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    void parseData(String weatherData){
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE);
            weatherDataList = mapper.readValue(weatherData, new TypeReference<List<WeatherData>>(){
            });
        } catch (IOException | NullPointerException ignore){}
    }
```

A snippet of my Activity_Main.xml if needed:

```
       <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/button1"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:onClick="button1Pressed" />
```

Comment: Googling for "OkHttp android example" and clicking the first link shows an example doing what you want to do in a correct way: https://www.journaldev.com/13629/okhttp-android-example-tutorial#processing-the-json-response

Comment: I'll take a look at it thank you!

Comment: "...the contents aren’t where i need them to be by the time I need to use them." – The solution for that is to not try to use them until the request completes. That is, don't set your `TextView`s until you're done in `parseData()`.